# Exact size(byte) of downloading file by torrent

Tags: download, bittorrent, qbittorrent

I am downloading(not finished) an ISO file by torrent.

I use qbittorrent, and it is easy to see the file size(after download complete) is about 4.2 GB.

But is it possible to know the exact size(as byte) of the ISO file(after download complete)?

Ideally, right after adding .torrent file.

(If it is possible) what if the torrent is not a single file, but folders and files mixed?

Any software, any method is welcome.

Comment: UTorrent 2.2.4 works well if you disable updates and view file details. ISOBURN and others can view the file contents in KB KiB or in any format

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you mean "exact size", then -
Just right click on file select properties. It's gonna display exact size in bytes, under the size on disk header.
On Linux, navigate to that directory where the file was downloaded and do a `ls -la`.